# How to Know if Socket Has Sent a File Properly

Tags: android, sockets

I am using a lot of sockets in my application to send files, but I still haven't figured out how can I make sure if the file Has been completely sent over the socket without any problem.

Here's my code:

```
           socket = new Socket(HOST, 1400);  
           System.out.println(socket);  
           System.out.println("Connecting...");  
           Log.i("Images","in the service"+filepath+"");    
           Log.i("Images","filepath in the async "+""+filepath+"");
           File fil=new File(filepath);  
           System.out.println(fil);
           System.out.println(fil.getName());     

           OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();    
           DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);   

           dos.writeInt(1);  
           dos.writeUTF(fil.getName());                    
            int filesize = (int) fil.length();  
            dos.writeInt(filesize); 

           byte [] buffer = new byte [filesize];  

           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fil.toString());    
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);    

           //Sending file name and file size to the server    
           bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); //This line is important  
           dos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);     

           fis.close();
           dos.flush();   

           //close socket connection  
          // socket.close();  

           dos.close();
           os.close(); 
           //socket.close();  
       }  
       catch(Exception e){  
           System.out.println("Error::"+e);  
           //System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
           //e.printStackTrace();  
           //Log.i("******* :( ", "UnknownHostException");  
       }
```

Comment: `//This line is important`. Indeed. And what is the return value of read()? You should use that in the next write().

Comment: yes, that goes to the buffer

Comment: Not in your code. So your code is buggy.

Comment: dude,upper of read , check the line : byte [] buffer = new byte [filesize]; there is no need to code like : byte [] aname = bis.read...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using TCP sockets, which guarantees that packets will either be sent, or an error will be reported. On Android, that error will be an IOException, that either write() or flush() will throw. In order to know if an error occurred, which means the data transfer wasn't complete, all you have to do is catch that IOException.

In other words, whatever comes after your call to flush(), will only be executed if the sending of data completed without errors.

You might want to return a response on the server as well, so it can report back to the client if part of the data wasn't complete.

Comment: Unfortunately it's incorrect. Transmission errors can occur after you call close(), in which case you have no way of knowing about them.

Comment: so i guess i can just move close after the catch

Comment: @reza No, because it can throw `IOException,` so you have to catch it. But you can't rely on the catch detecting all transmission errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have the receiver send you an acknowledgment when he's received all the data. Then you know all the data got all the way to the application. Nothing else can tell you that.

NB as per @greenapp's comment above, your code isn't correct. You're assuming that read() fills the buffer. The canonical way to copy streams in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

This works with any non-zero size buffer. It isn't necessary to allocate a buffer the size of the file. Use this at both ends. If you need to read up to a specific length sent beforehand, you need to keep track of how much you've read and make sure you only read exactly that many bytes in the loop. The required modification is trivial:

```
while (total < length && (count = in.read(buffer, 0, length-total > buffer.length ? buffer.length : (int)(length-total)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    total += count;
}
```

E&OE